# CSS media queries for Galaxy S3

Tags: css, html, media-queries, responsive-design

Anyone know how to target the Samsung Galaxy S3 with media queries?

Currently I use:

## iPad

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (device-width: 768px)"                                                href="css/device-768.css"/>
```

## Other tablet devices

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 767px) and (min-device-width: 641px)" href="css/device-max767.css"/>
```

## Phones (S3 didnt use this - dont know why)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"    href="css/phones.css"/>
```

I also tested

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"    href="css/phones.css"/>
```

but it didnt work...

Comment: Aren't those 'testing' screen resolution rather than devices?

Comment: What is the pixel dimensions of the S3?  Once you know that you can target with a simple max width / height media query.  The bigger question here is why aren't you using device agnostic media query breakpoints.

Comment: I don't think that media queries are suitable to target devices. That's the wrong question to ask.

Comment: i dont want to target specific devices, but i want all phones to use the same css - but sadly the s3 isnt a target of my querry. so im surching a querry which targets the s3...

Comment: Well that's just not desirable. Not all phones are the same size. Much better to target for screen size not "what the device is". You are thinking about it wrong. For example, What is a Galaxy Note?

Comment: hm, i dont want to target 20 different screen size... currently i have a floating layout with elemnts size like this: 1-1-1, 2-1, 3, 1-2... i want 3 different views - for pc/laptops: original size and margins; for pads: no margins between the elements; for phones: alle elements size 100%... so i think my trying to target the s3 isnt as bad...

Comment: I'm with the OP on this - The question has not been answered, and is still valid. I, for example, am building an extremely large responsive site at the moment, and there are certain pieces of functionality that are different for desktop and mobile. The Galaxy S3 is a problem for us because it has a high-density display, but still reports its actual pixel dimensions (unlike Apple's more sensible approach which is to divide the number of actual pixels by the pixel ratio and report that as the size).

Answer (score 49):

I have set up a page that shows you how any device will react to media queries by giving the values of the media features. Just visit the page with the device you want to test:

http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html

From there, you can decide which media query you want to use based on what the different devices report. Remember it is generally a bad idea to target specific devices. You should rather target display sizes and density to make your website adapt to the surface at hand.

Comment: Nice Job Pieroxy. This helped me a lot.

Comment: This is very useful - here's a shortened link for convenience http://is.gd/Rc2wwb

Comment: Very nice. One interesting feature (not necessarily due to your tests) is that the landscape and portrait numbers don't just swap, but change when tested on my Samsung Galaxy S4. Portrait width:360px, height:567px. Landscape width:640px, height:287px. I don't know much about this stuff, but it seems odd to me.

Comment: @PeterGross In case this is still odd to you, that's because you have other elements that use your some of the available space. Like the action bar for example, portrait or landscape it will always take space from your height, hence why you'll not be able to simply swap the values.

Answer (score 14):

At this time, mobile devices have improved so much that their screen resolutions are similar and sometimes even better than desktop screens resolutions.

For example Galaxy S4 of Samsung has 1080X1920 pixels - Full HD screen!

But in responsive design we check resolution and need to fit according the resolution and if you try to add media query, let's say min-width of 1000px and check it on the Samsung Galaxy S4 you will see that nothing happened.

The reason for it is that mobile high density screen have two aspect of pixels.

Real resolution
The first resolution is the factory real resolution, it's mostly for videos and images. on Samsung galaxy S4 the real resolution is 1080X1920.

CSS resolution
The second resolution is for the browser. and for us developers that means we need to act different and not according the real screen resolution. in Samsung Galaxy S4, CSS resolution is 360X640.

Samsung Galaxy S4 resolution:
Real resolution: 1080X1920
CSS resolution: 360X640

How to acquire CSS resolution? In Wikipedia you have all mobile devices resolution table (tablet and mobile devices). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density

```
/*(ldpi) Android*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:.75){

  /*CSS  */
}

/*(mdpi) Android*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 480px) and (max-device-width : 800px) {

  /*CSS  */
}

/*(hdpi) Android*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5){

  /*CSS  */

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this rundown. I would vote up your answer twice.

Answer (score 9):

I used this to target just the portrait view on the s3:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 719px) and (max-device-width : 721px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation : portrait) { 

}
```

Comment: Very specific to the S3, but it does answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

Like mentioned before. Use this [**Media Query detector**](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html) on your handset and also consider using a better fluid design - CSS hacks are not good - you should not really need them in 90% of scenarios if you have a good fluid design.

## Samsung Galaxy S3

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 720px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  .your-css{}
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1280px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  .your-css{}
}
```

Comment: Aside from answering the question, this would create problems differentiating styling between the phone and tablet device in general?

Comment: Yes it is a bit out dated now my approach. Too many devices and tablets. Best approach IMO is responsive design - dedicated responsive mobile site and dedicated separate store for tablet and web - depends on the scenario though.

Comment: Does that not rather miss the point of using responsive at all? Should be "one website for all devices", really.

Comment: I said scenario depending. We have a semi responsive desktop site and optimisation for tablet. We also have a dedicated fully responsive mobile web app.

Answer (score 5):

Samsung Galaxy S I & II: 320 x 533, in portrait mode (CSS pixel density is 1.5)

Samsung Galaxy S III: **360 x 640**, in portrait mode

Comment: good answer, as it gives the details to fix this guys problem, instead of convincing him his technique isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

On my Samsung S3 with Android 4.1.2, while I tried all the media query features (max-height, width, device height and width and even color:8) only this worked for me in addition to **the second answer above** in this page:

## Samsung S3 default browser

```
/* Samsung S3 default browser portrait*/
@media only screen and (device-width: 720px) and (device-height: 1280px) and (orientation: portrait) {
body { background:yellow;} 
}

/* Samsung S3 default browser landscape */
@media only screen and (device-width: 1280px) and (device-height: 720px) and (orientation: landscape)  {
body { background:#000;} 
}
```

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ234.png) for the [pieroxy](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html) media query diagnostic tool test. **Please note** that both work without orientation but don't change the propriety without load/refresh.

Hope this helps with no conflict with any other queries you might use

Answer (score 0):

I think this would safely apply to most phones of today (HTCs, iPhones, Samsung), while avoiding the common tablet widths (iPad iPad 3/4 iOS 6 has **672px** on portrait).

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/Styles/device_phone.css' media='screen and (max-width: 640px)'/>
```

This phone would be the odd fish:

*Samsung Nexus S Android 2.3.6 Stock Browser* which has
width: 480px, height: **800px** (max-width 800)

It is generally not recommended to target specific devices, but if you really wanted to target the odd fish you could, since it has other unique attributes. I personally prefer using max-width as I can test direct on my desktop and wide screen, and I'm not fussed for users seeing the mobile view if they really did resize their browser to less than 640 wide.

Reference:
http://pieroxy.net/blog/2012/10/18/media_features_of_the_most_common_devices.html

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and worked.

```
@media only screen and
(device-width: 720px) and
(device-height: 1280px)  and
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

Answer (score -2):

Forget all this "max-device-width" "min-height", etc, quackery!The problem is you guys are not designing for the dimensions of the device. Also, the Galaxy S3 according to Samsung has a pixel density of 2, meaning that the physical screen maps out 1 device pixel to 2 CSS pixels. If this is true then the 720x1280 resolution is only a logical resolution and not the real physical resolution of the device! This is also the case with the Apple iphone 4 which has a specified resolution of 640x960px, which is actually the logical resolution and NOT the real resolution of the actual device. The real physical resolution for the iphone is half this number after taking into account pixel density, meaning its physical dimensions are actually 320x480, which is true since I use this code all the time!

Therefore, if the S3 also has a pixel density of 2, then its real native resolution is actually 360x640px, NOT 720x960 as Samsung stated. Again, the device maps out 2 CSS pixels to 1 device pixel! Also, why on earth are people use variable media queries, quackery I tell you!

```
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) {
```

Styles go here 
}

```
@media screen and (device-width: 640px) and (device-height: 360px) and (orientation: landscape) {
```

Styles here
}
OR:
You can just state the logical resolution which was provided by Samsung, DuH!, Rocket science right?

```
@media screen and (width: 720px) and (height: 1280px) and (orientation: portrait) {
```

Styles
}

```
@media screen and (width: 1280px) and (height: 720px) and (orientation: landscape) {
```

Styles
}
Very simple! Thats all there is to it. And people wonder why they cant get media queries to work, yet they use all these variable values. Try actually targeting the resolution for the device. There's no reason on earth to ever use variable values such as "max-width", etc.

Comment: -1 I think that there are many reasons to use `max-width` (and others) instead of targeting specific devices' specifications. The most important reason is that I don't want to have to care about every device under the sun; targeting groups of devices by using `max-width` allows me to only maintain 3 different sets of styles: desktop, tablet, and phone. Another important reason is because I don't want to have to update my CSS/website every time a new device is released, I can be confident that most new devices will fall into the correct bounds of `max-width` I have already established.

Comment: The S3 also returns `360px` for `width`, not just `device-width`.  I believe the difference between the two is down to scrollbars and address-bar (which are included in `device-width` but not `width`), not the real versus logical resolutions.