# Media Queries for Android

Tags: android, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to set up MQ's to make a site responsive. I have it linked and everything it working fine, with one caveat the `max-width: 480px` doesn't work for droid. It does recognize my mobile stylesheet when I up the max-width to around 900px.

I haven't been able to find an answer to this yet, I have played around with some viewport tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
```

What is the best way to target Android phones using media queries?

Comment: It's not likely, but it may be worth checking to see if `@viewport` rules work:  http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/

Answer (score 1):

One problem you might be running into is the fact that Android phones, even more so then Apple phones, have varying pixel widths.

For example, if you were testing on a Samsung Galaxy S3 or S4, the pixel width of those phones is well beyond 480px in landscape mode, even accounting for pixel density, so the media query would never fire. When it comes to some of the newer devices, you are better off to target user agent and then serve mobile queries based on that header response.

Also, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12949598/1636704) for more details on testing for mobile devices.

Comment: So would I target the `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio`? I am still a bit unclear as to how to solve the problem, the diagnostic tool is very neat though.

Comment: Right, so you could try a combination of the device-pixel-ratio and min-width and max-width to target the droid incredible 2, but if in the end the pixel width is still 800px, you are going to have to write a media query to target that device.

A better approach would be to use the user-agent to target the device, or by using [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com) you could serve specific styles only to html.touch, which would target all mobile and tablet devices.

Answer (score 0):

You want to start by changing your meta tag to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Good luck!

Comment: Tried that and no luck, I am testing on a droid incredible 2, and it works in Firefox's responsive mode, just on the droid I need to adjust the width all the way up to 800px, and that would overlap with iPads and other devices

Comment: To clarify, when you say max-width: 480px doesn't work for droid, does the layout not look good?

Comment: No, for now I am just changing some colors to test the connection and ensure the size specifications works, when I set to 480px the text is still black (default stylesheet), only turns red (for the mobile stylesheet) at 800px and up.

Comment: Have you tried <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> only ie no second target-densityDpi=device-dpi meta tag

Comment: Yeah, tried doing them individually and had the same result. It seems to be working with `(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.4)` but my concern is, I don't have all the devices to see what the effects this might have on other devices

Comment: Have you triple checked that your media queries are in the correct order, after the default CSS styles, so that the cascading works as you intend, and that you don't have any overlap in the medai queries, ie you could have something like max-width 480 px, text red followed by min-width:481px and max width: 800px; text:something else