# Media Queries for Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, css, responsive-design, media-queries, galaxy

I have a portfolio website that I'm trying to make responsive, and I'd like to be able to show it to people on my S3, although I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work using media queries. I used the diagnostic tool [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036337/css-media-queries-for-galaxy-s3) and got two different values of device width across the two browsers installed on the phone (Samsung's default browser, and Chrome), so I've just been using "width" combined with device pixel ratio.

Here's what I have in my stylesheet:

```
body, html
{
    display: block;
    font-family: quicksand, arial;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 22em) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{ 
    #container
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }   
}
```

For some reason, the background color is still red, even when I view the page on the S3.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `em` instead of `px`?

Comment: Not really, it doesn't seem to work when I have (max-width: 360px) either though...

Comment: Can you try with `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5` and see if it works?

Comment: And if not, can you try with `max-device-width`? I believe that would be 720px. You would need to check on [pieroxy test features](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html)

Comment: Still doesn't work :-(

Comment: Aha, `@media only screen and (max-device-width:720px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)` worked! Thank you! :-)

Comment: Cool... You can thank the guys from that other thread you linked in your question :)

Answer (score 4):

On my Samsung S3 with Android 4.1.2, while I tried all the media query features (max-height, width, device height and width and even color:8) only this worked for me:

```
/* Samsung S3 default browser portrait*/
@media only screen and (device-width: 720px) and (device-height: 1280px) and (orientation: portrait) {
body { background:yellow;} 
}

/* Samsung S3 default browser landscape */
@media only screen and (device-width: 1280px) and (device-height: 720px) and (orientation: landscape)  {
body { background:#000;} 
}
```

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ234.png) for the [pieroxy](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html) media query diagnostic tool test for all possible queries.

**Please note** that both work without orientation but don't change the propriety without load/refresh.

Hope this helps with no conflict with any other queries you might use